# Why RtlCopyMemory failed

Tags: c++, wdk

All, I was trying to use `RtlCopyMemory` to duplicate a structure instance, But seems it didn't successfully copy the instance before the callback returns. I didn't know if I missed something, Please help to review the below code. Thanks.

```
#define RtlZeroMemory(Destination,Length) memset((Destination),0,(Length))
#define RtlCopyMemory(Destination,Source,Length) memcpy((Destination),(Source),(Length))

typedef struct _FLT_RELATED_OBJECTS {

    USHORT CONST Size;
    USHORT CONST TransactionContext;            //TxF mini-version
    PFLT_FILTER CONST Filter;
    PFLT_VOLUME CONST Volume;
    PFLT_INSTANCE CONST Instance;
    PFILE_OBJECT CONST FileObject;
    PKTRANSACTION CONST Transaction;

} FLT_RELATED_OBJECTS, *PFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS;

FLT_POSTOP_CALLBACK_STATUS
CreateBackUpFile_WhenPostCreatedCallback (
    _Inout_ PFLT_CALLBACK_DATA Data,
    _In_ PCFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS FltObjects,
    _In_ PVOID CompletionContext,
    _In_ FLT_POST_OPERATION_FLAGS Flags
    )
{
   PFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS copiedRelatedObj;
   ...
   RtlZeroMemory(&copiedRelatedObj, FltObjects->Size);
   KdBreakPoint();
   RtlCopyMemory(&copiedRelatedObj,FltObjects,FltObjects->Size);
   DbgPrint("The file name in the FltObjects is : %s\n",FltObjects->FileObject->FileName);
   DbgPrint("The file name in the Duplicated FltObjects is : %s\n",copiedRelatedObj->FileObject->FileName);
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*RtlZeroMemory* requires **pointer** to a memory block as its first argument. But you give it **pointer to pointer** ( as PFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS is already a pointer ). Use

```
FLT_RELATED_OBJECTS copiedRelatedObj;
```

Comment: Does it mean `RtlZeroMemory(copiedRelatedObj, FltObjects->Size);` would work too ?If I keep the `PFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS copiedRelatedObj;` right ? thanks.

Comment: Joe.wang, yes `RtlZeroMemory(copiedRelatedObj, FltObjects->Size);` would work, but then you need to initialise copiedRelatedObj first.

Answer (score 1):

```
   PFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS copiedRelatedObj;
```

The *copiedRelatedObj* variable is a **pointer**.  It is not initialized.  Yell a bit invisible Microsoft C programmers for that dreadful habit of declaring pointer types.  Then remove the P.  Fix:

```
   FLT_RELATED_OBJECTS copiedRelatedObj;
```

Comment: Forgive me I just learned c program, Can I initialized a pointer variable by `ExAllocatePoolWithTag` function? Currently I was using this function to try to initialize pointer. thanks. +1

Comment: Sure.  As long as you release it again.  Favor local variables where possible.  And remove the & operator if you actually intend to allocate the memory.